# Python doesn't let me change the number of axis ticks when using subplots

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

I have code which looks like this:

```
plt.figure()

plt.subplot(211)
plt.plot(timestamps_SW, np.random.randn(len(testLabelsSW_ds)), label='truth')
plt.plot(timestamps_SW, np.random.randn(len(testLabelsSW_ds)), label='pred.')
plt.locator_params(axis='y', nbins=5)
plt.legend()

plt.subplot(212)
plt.plot(timestamps_SE,np.random.randn(len(testLabelsSE_ds)), label='truth')
plt.plot(timestamps_SE,np.random.randn(len(testLabelsSE_ds)), label='pred.')
plt.locator_params(axis='y', nbins=5)
plt.legend()
```

The resulting plot looks as such:

[image: [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/JsYKw.png]

Clearly each y-axis doesn't have 5 ticks. How do I fix?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `plt.locator_params(..., nbins=5)` you ask the default locator to use 5 bins. The default locator is an `AutoLocator`. It's a subclass of the `MaxNLocator`. *MaxN* means, it will try to find a maximum of `N` nice locations, where `N` is equal to `nbins + 1`. 
"Nice" locations means, e.g. something like 1.0, 0.25 etc are considered "nice", while something like 0.761 is of course not so nice.

The two constraints (a) "nice" and (b) "N locations" are of course seldomly fulfillable at the same time. Therefore "nice" has priority here.

If you leave out the constraint (a), you can get `N` locations simply by placing the ticks manually,

```
plt.yticks(np.linspace(*plt.ylim(), 5))
```